# How to combine two records in the same table

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

[image: Table 1]

The table is grouped by `option_date`, `Option_symbol`, `option_expire_month` and `option_strike`.  For those records that have the same strike price, I would like to combine them. So in my table above, record 2 and 3 when combined would look something like this:

[image: Table 2]

Note that for every record that has an `option_type = C`, the value for `option_put_volume` is 0.  And for every record that has an `option_type = P`, the value for `option_call_volume` is 0.

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the actual details in the text instead of in images. Graphics should only be used when absolutely necessary to illustrate your point. They can't be copied and pasted from to create test tables or data, and are somewhat unfair to users who have limited bandwidth or are behind proxy servers that won't allow access to them. In addition, if the links are not available for some reason, there is no content here in your question that will be useful to future users of this site searching for a solution to their own problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you basically want to group the rows, which you could do using the group by query. Identify all the columns that you would want to group by and use them in the select clause. For the option_call_volume and option_put_volume, you could just sum them up.

You could do something like this:

```
Select option_date, option_symbol, option_price, option_expire_month, option_strike, sum(option_call_volume), sum(option_put_volume) 
from table 
group by option_date, option_symbol, option_price, option_expire_month, option_strike
```

Comment: I guess I could put this into an insert statement to create a new table then delete my existing table.  This will work great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword **Group by** in SQL Syntax base on column that you want to group.
And you can use select **Case** keyword for generate value base on your criteria.

Here is the example link for that SQL keyword :

[GROUP BY - SQL Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[CASE - SQL Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)